# How to disable this Netbeans highlighting?

Tags: netbeans

I'm not sure if StackOverflow is the right site for this question but i don't think I'd get better help from other than developers here.

Basically Netbeans keeps highlighting scripting in ERB or HTML files. I tried to disable many things in `tools -> options -> fonts & colors`. But none worked.

[image]

Any one knows how to get rid of that? It appears on all themes.

Comment: The [FAQ includes if your question generally covers … _software tools commonly used by programmers_ … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 0):

Old Queston, but still relevant, (and in other IDEs as well). For Netbeans v8, you will find most of the old links / themes unusable.  But there is a way.

Go to Tools -> Plugins and search 'theme' and you will get "Dark Look And Feel Themes"

The default that came up after a reboot did NOT have the ugly highlighting on scripts, and it is easy on the eyes (unlike the default theme), plus it has good color-highlighting for "html.erb" files.  The controller code could use some work on the highlighting, but I can live with it.

And before anyone points it out - yes, official support was dropped by NB for Ruby.  The community, however, has done a great job via plugins keeping the Ruby/Rails support working.